# Pandas reset_index() creating level0 column

Tags: sql, python-3.x, pandas, duplicates, multiple-columns

I'm reading one `CSV` file eliminating the duplicates and exporting to a database.

The problem here is that it is creating a column called `level0` instead of resetting the index.

Here is my code

```
df = pd.read_csv('SampleData.csv', sep=';', encoding='latin1',  low_memory=False)
df_projects = df['External'].drop_duplicates()
df_projects = df_projects.to_frame()
df_projects.rename(columns={'External': 'name'}, inplace=True)
df_projects = df_projects.reset_index()

con = create_engine('sqlite:///db.sqlite3')
df_projects.to_sql("inventory_projects", con, index=True, if_exists='replace')
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need add parameter `drop=True` to [`reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html):

```
...
df_projects = df_projects.rename('name').to_frame()
df_projects = df_projects.reset_index(drop=True)
...
```